# snowflake table creation 08_15_2022

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

*how to perform joins and how to maintain warehouse?*

I have tried:
create table table_name values i int, nm string;

How to create a role in snowflake without any privileges or minimum privileges ?

I tried to create a role with parent role security-admin .

when I assign this role to user i am able to see databases of parent role also.

After I created role with parent role as public still I am able to see databases

what shall I do that a created role should not have access to any unless I grant it ?

Comment: Please provide the actual statements you are executing and the results you are seeing.  When you say you created a role with parent of security_admin, be sure that you don't have your logic backwards where your role inherits the privileges of security_admin.

Comment: What's the question here? How to create a table? How to perform a join? How to create a role? Voting to close as the question needs focus

Answer (score 0):

When you CREATE ROLE, it's an independent object and does not come with any privileges:

```
use role accountadmin;
create role empty_role;
show grants to role empty_role;
```

The last command does not return anything even if it is created by the accountadmin role.

```
grant role empty_role to user gokhan;
use role empty_role;
show databases;
```

As the new role has no additional access, the last command shows the databases which the PUBLIC role has access. I hope this explains why you see some databases when you switch to your new role.